# How to add two variables in the same case in a table

Tags: tables

In fact, I want to add two variable (de,e) in the same case as illustrated in this figure below:

[image]

and here is the code that I have written, but I don't know how to make that de and e in the same place:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Définitions des variables linguistiques}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c c c} 
\toprule
\makecell{de} & \makecell{ NB}& \makecell{NM} & \makecell{NS} & \makecell{Z} 
& \makecell{PS}& \makecell{PM} & \makecell{PB}  \\ 
\midrule
NB &  Z & PS & PM & NB & NM & NS & Z\\
NM &  NS & Z & PS & NM & NS & Z & PS\\
NS &  NM & NS & Z & NS & Z & PS & PM\\
Z &  NB & NM & NS & Z & PS & PM & PB\\
PS &  NB & NB & NM & PS & PM & PB & PB\\
PM &  NB & NB & NB & PM & PB & PB & PB\\
PB &  NB & NB & NB & PB & PB & PB & PB\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is not very clear. What do you mean with `in the same place`?

Comment: e above of de as shown in the figure with that \

Comment: Have a look at the diagbox package.

Comment: @TeXnician \ it's not really important the important for me is to have e above of de

Comment: That's what I meant with *have a look*, because the package does *exactly* what you want!

Comment: @TeXnician even though one might clearly state "I want" and trick people into believing the premise, one might just be in the dark about one's own wishes, which is clearly illustrated in [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431967/117274) `;@)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the package `diagbox`.

[image: diagbox]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Définitions des variables linguistiques}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c c c} 
\toprule
\diagbox{de}{e} & \makecell{ NB}& \makecell{NM} & \makecell{NS} & \makecell{Z} 
& \makecell{PS}& \makecell{PM} & \makecell{PB}  \\ 
\midrule
NB &  Z & PS & PM & NB & NM & NS & Z\\
NM &  NS & Z & PS & NM & NS & Z & PS\\
NS &  NM & NS & Z & NS & Z & PS & PM\\
Z &  NB & NM & NS & Z & PS & PM & PB\\
PS &  NB & NB & NM & PS & PM & PB & PB\\
PM &  NB & NB & NB & PM & PB & PB & PB\\
PB &  NB & NB & NB & PB & PB & PB & PB\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it's good but as you can see the vertical line isn't aligned with  de and the same thing for e. But anyway thank you so very much

Answer (score 4):

This is just as clear and avoids the horrible diagonal line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed for LaTeX 2018-04-01 or later
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\caption{Définitions des variables linguistiques}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c c c c c c c c @{}}
\toprule

de & \multicolumn{7}{c}{e} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-8}
   & NB & NM & NS & Z  & PS & PM & PB \\ 
\midrule
NB & Z  & PS & PM & NB & NM & NS & Z  \\
NM & NS & Z  & PS & NM & NS & Z  & PS \\
NS & NM & NS & Z  & NS & Z  & PS & PM \\
Z  & NB & NM & NS & Z  & PS & PM & PB \\
PS & NB & NB & NM & PS & PM & PB & PB \\
PM & NB & NB & NB & PM & PB & PB & PB \\
PB & NB & NB & NB & PB & PB & PB & PB \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to place de at the same level of the horizontal line?

Comment: @pzorba75 You probably do not really want this, but if you insist you could try the `multirow` package.

Comment: @pzorba75 Placing “de” lower would suggest a relevance for both lines to its right, which is not the case. Placing it at the same level as “e” clarifies it just refers to the column below it.